# Discovering an error after publishing?

Tags: publications, research-process, errors-erratum

My paper was published 6 months ago. A few days ago, while reading it I discovered that one of the equations had the wrong power: instead of *x* it should have *x²*. After checking my old notes it turns out that they had *x²*, so its just a typing error. I should point out that this doesn't change the end result and the equation before and after it are both correct.

What should I do? Should I tell the journal about this mistake?

Answer (score 13):

This is the sort of thing that corrections and errata are for. The journal should have a procedure for informing the editorial staff and correcting the record.  Follow it, and you should be able to fairly quickly and easily correct the record.